# ASP.Net MVC 3: Custom data binder to transform data coming from/going to the DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, model-binding

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC 3 project where I would like to encrypt all emails stored in a database for additional protection in case some hacker would ever get access to the db, and I was wondering what was the best way to achieve this.

I read a bit about custom model binders, but this is for the binding between the controller and the view. I am not sure if this is what I want, since I may need to have access to unencrypted email addresses in the code (in the Service Layer, where I have the Business Rules). **So I would have preferred the encryption/decryption to occur automatically when the model is saved to/loaded from the database, and this is what I don't know how to do.**

We can imagine that I have this POCO model:

```
public partial class Contact
{  
    public virtual int ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is a way to have the Email property encrypted when it is persisted to the database and decrypted when it is loaded from the database.

One way to do it would be to have an extra UnencryptedEmail property in my Contact model that would have a getter and a setter that would decrypt and encrypt the Email property, but I find that having to add an extra property is not as clean a solution.

If, for some reason, using a custom IModelBinder is the way to go, please let me know why and tell me how to get it to be applied only on the Email property of the Contact model. Up to now, I have only seen implementations for applying transformations on all properties of a specific data type.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Model View approach instead of directly binding to models and displaying them in the Views.

As for encryption and decryption there are tons of approaches you can employ.

Comment: I am already using View Models. This is not the problem. I would like the email addresses to be unencrypted when dealing with my models in my business/service layer. Encryption/Decryption is not a problem either. I already have everything I need for this. Sorry, if this was not clear in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I can see what you are looking for, instead of answering and explaining the whole stuff, I can point you to a related material which is not exactly what your requirement is but you can take a cue from it.

http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/

In the above code first membership provider code, the passwords are hashed and stored in database and for comparison the hashing is removed and then they are compared.

I understand it will be time consuming but its worth to take a look at.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the model binder is the right way to go. The encryption of an email sounds like a business requirement and as such I would place it in the business layer.

When storing the email, your business layer would get the plain email address as input from the application layer, encrypt it and pass the encrypted value to the repository.

When retrieving the email, your business layer would receive the email in an encrypted state from the repository, decrypt it and pass it back to the application layer.

Unless you require it, the application layer would not need to know about the encrypted version of the email as it only deals with the plain version of it. On the other end the repository would not need to know about the decrypted version of the email as it only needs to deal with the encrypted version of it. To that end the business layer does sound like the best place to handle this.

Comment: I would prefer this to happen automatically though, without having to worry about passing the email through a function to encrypt/decrypt it. It would be to easy to forget. I also think that a model binder (doing the binding between the controllers and the views) is not the way to go. I don't know how this binder is called, but I would prefer this to happen in the binder transferring data between the database and my POCO entities.

Comment: I don't think writing code to try and compensate for a developers possible forgetfulness is a good reason. You can use integration tests to verify business logic is applied. You can have a test which will ensure emails are encrypted when written to the database within your Contact integration tests. Those tests will start failing as soon as the email is not encrypted any more. If developers start to forget to implement business logic and no procedure is in place to catch this (code reviews, automated testing, manual testing, etc.) I think you might have a other things to worry about.